# What's the cleanest implementation of this text arrangement in CSS+HTML?

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

I'm trying to discover a clean way of implementing this text arrangement (INCLUDING the two curly braces) in CSS, but I'm curious if there is already a best practice for doing so. Is three divs the only way to accomplish this?

[image: arranged text]

Comment: Can you elaborate James? What are you expecting to achieve?

Comment: It depends on what you are trying to do. That could be a list or it could be paragraphs or anything else.

Comment: @Sole I want to actually include the large brackets in the implementation.  So it will essentially be a list of text surrounded by two very large brackets. The list should be vertically aligned, I might add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways you could achieve the text arrangement, you can write this text either in a `<p>` tag like so:

```
<p>
  line 1 <br/>
  line 2 <br/>
  line 3 <br/>
  line 4 <br/>
  line 5 <br/>
</p>
```

Or you could write it as a list like so:

```
<ul>
  <li>line 1</li>
  <li>line 2</li>
  <li>line 3</li>
  <li>line 4</li>
  <li>line 5</li>
</ul>
```

If you decide to use the list HTML, you may need to declare the following CSS:

```
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rbnottcu/1/) is a link to a working fiddle.

Both the above methods are good practise and at the end of the day it is up to you and which method you prefer.

**Updated Answer**

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/rbnottcu/3/) is an updated fiddle to achieve what you want, the best way is to have 4 divs, here is the HTML:

```
<div class="block">
  <div class="block__bg-1"></div>
  <div class="block__module">
    <h2>List</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>line 1</li>
      <li>line 2</li>
      <li>line 3</li>
      <li>line 4</li>
      <li>line 5</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="block__bg-2"></div>
</div>
```

The reason for so many divs is because the `block__module--bg` divs are holding background images for the curly braces and the `block` and `block__module` divs are being used to vertically align the content using `display: table` `display:table-cell` and `vertical-align:middle` method.

Here is the CSS:

```
.block {
  display:table;
  height:400px;
}

.block__module {
  display:table-cell;
  vertical-align:middle;
}

.block__bg-1,
.block__bg-2 {
  height:400px;
  width:50px;
  background: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/6/68/GullBraceLeft.svg/2000px-GullBraceLeft.svg.png") no-repeat center;
  background-size:contain;
}

.block__bg-2 {
  transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, I want to actually render the two large brackets on either side of the text, and have the text between them render as vertically aligned.

Comment: @JamesBecker I have updated my answer and the fiddle, take a look > https://jsfiddle.net/rbnottcu/3/

Comment: Thanks! @Neelam Khan

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I finally implemented it, although I'm still open to other suggestions:

CSS:

```
.center {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin:0 0 0.5em 0;
    font-weight:200;
    line-height:1.6em;
}

.brackets {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    font-size: 144px; !important
    position: absolute; !important
    left: 300px; !important
}
```

HTML:

```
<div style="display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; position:relative;">
    <div class="brackets" style="display: table-cell">{</div>
    <div class="center" style="text-align: center" style="display: table-cell">
        line1<br>
        line2<br>
        line3<br>
        line4<br>
        line5
    </div>
    <div class="brackets" style="display: table-cell">}</div>
</div>
```

Comment: instead of the brackets `div` you can use a before and after. `.center:before{ //css here }` for example. Also you shouldn't use `!important` unless you really need to.